# swipe dynamic layers using spy glass in ol3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, html, css

I am working on swipe based ol3 web application where i want to use spy glass for dynamic added layers.
I have seen [layer spy](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/layer-spy.html) example but this is only for single layer swipe ..
I want for dynamic layers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic added layers'? are they added after map initialization?

Comment: yes.-@ChaseChoi

Comment: Have you tried adding precompose, postcompose event on both layers which you want to clip? layer1 (bg), layer2, layer3 -- for layer2 and layer3

Comment: Yes,it works for predefined layer,,but i want to spyglass functionality for dynamically added layers..@ChaseChoi

Comment: Why not? just like this: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbNpMM?editors=0010). layers are added at the bottom of the code.